# Hiding the image button in edit row in GridView in C#

Tags: c#, gridview

I have a `GridView` in C# displaying person records

For a single person I can have a single code or multiple associated codes.

Once the person is recognized, a `List<string>` with his codes is created:

```
List<string> codList = new List<string>();
string ns;

if (reader.HasRows)
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        cod = reader["cod"].ToString();
        codList.Add(cod.ToString());
        aut = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Aut"]);
    }

    ns = "";
    ns = string.Join(",", (from cod in codList select "?").ToList());
}
```

For this person the list of codes contains these values:

```
32D
32B
33E
33G
35H
```

Now I need to hide the image button for the edit row in the GridView, if the value of the variable `aut` is greater than zero and if the value of the `cod` column corresponds to the values in the `list`:

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    string cod = Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "cod"));
    ImageButton btnEdit = (ImageButton)e.Row.FindControl("imgbtnEdit");

    foreach (var co in codList)
    {
        if (aut > 0 && cod.ToString().Contains(co.ToString()))
        {
            btnEdit.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            btnEdit.Visible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

But the button for edit row in `GridView` is visible only for last value of `list`

```
35H
```

Instead for others values of `list` the button for edit row in `GridView` is hidden.

```
32D
32B
33E
33G
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your problem fully, but I see an issue:

```cs
if (aut > 0 && cod.ToString().Contains(co.ToString()))
{
    btnEdit.Visible = true;
}
else
{
    btnEdit.Visible = true;
}
```

That evaluates to btnEdit.Visible = true, no matter your condition. I think you meant:

```cs
btnEdit.Visible = (aut > 0 && cod.ToString().Contains(co.ToString());
```

Also evaluating it in a for loop makes very little difference as it's the same btnEdit you set every time. That probably explains why it's the last value that sticks.